# Input value change not detected

Tags: jquery, onchange

```
var input = $('input[type="number"]', this);
$('.inc').on('click', function(){
  input.val( parseFloat(input.val()) + parseFloat(0.5));
});
```

... increments the value of the input correctly. However, I can't get `change` event with:

```
$('input[type="number"]').on('propertychange change keyup input paste', function(){
  console.log('change'); 
});
```

What am I doing wrong here?

https://jsfiddle.net/cf5vhb2c/

Comment: a quick turn around is to explicitly call the function after increment. A snippet would be appreciated though.

Comment: According to [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change), "...Unlike the input event, the `change` event is not necessarily fired for each change to an element's value.". Perhaps these events are not being fired because your are changing the value dynamically and not as a result of user interaction.

Comment: Updated the description with a quick fiddle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to trigger `change` too, because a programatically set of the value will not trigger any event by default.

```
var input = $('input[type="number"]', this);
$('.inc').on('click', function(){
    input.val(parseFloat(input.val()) + parseFloat(0.5)).trigger("change");
});
```

---

Beside this you need to declare your `updateTotal` function befor using it in the event listener creation.

```
var updateTotal = function() {
    console.log('change');
}
$('.hours input[type="number"]').on('change', updateTotal);
```

Or declare a named function:

```
$('.hours input[type="number"]').on('change', updateTotal);
function updateTotal() {
    console.log('change');
}
```

Or use a anonymous function directly:

```
$('.hours input[type="number"]').on('change', function() {
    console.log('change');
});
```

**[Working example.](https://jsfiddle.net/cf5vhb2c/3/)**

Comment: Just tried, doesn't work either. I must be doing something stupid. Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cf5vhb2c/

Comment: Edited my answer with your fiddle @3zzy!

Comment: That worked, looks like I was using the function before it was declared?

Comment: Yes and no. You used a variable with a anonymous function. If you would write `function updateTotal() { /**/ }` it would work too ... @3zzy

Answer (score -1):

You can always call a function after changing the value:

```
var input = $('input[type="number"]', this);
$('.inc').on('click', function(){
  input.val( parseFloat(input.val()) + parseFloat(0.5));
  do_something();
});

function do_something() {
   console.log('change'); 
}
```

Ofcourse you have to change this code too, to execute all in one function:

```
$('input[type="number"]').on('propertychange change keyup input paste', function(){
  do_something();
});
```

Another thing that comes in my mind is the following, didn't test it though:

```
$('.inc').on('click', function(){
  input.val( parseFloat(input.val()) + parseFloat(0.5)).trigger('change');
});
```